# Oracle Golden Gate with Cassandra

Tags: oracle, cassandra, replication, oracle-golden-gate

I am pretty new to Oracle Golden Gate, wanted to understand if it possible to create a bidirectional sync between Oracle 12x and Cassandra(DSE) using Oracle Golden Gate? Searched several places in internet but most examples are replicating data between Oracle databases. I started wondering if it is even possible to do so. Can anyone help me with any documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate module called Oracle GoldenGate for BigData. It supports many NoSQL replication targets.
One of the supported BigData databases is also Apache Cassandra.

There is a separate [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/bd123010/gg-bd/GADBD/GUID-EE8CD5B5-8749-4906-B50C-EE33E36AC984.htm) explaining how to use it.

There is no separate module that allows you to connect Apache Cassandra as the source of your replication. If you need such replication you need to provide some intermediate step. The source of replication for Oracle GoldenGate can only be a database (Oracle, TimesTen, DB2, Informix, MySQL, MS SQL Server, NonStop SQL/MX, SAP/Sybase ASE, Teradata) or a JMS queue.